# $.extend ignoring 'traditional' flag

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC4 application, and as such, all array data sent to the server over ajax must be sent using the `traditional` option. (no `[]` for POST variables).

The problem is, I also have a filter set-up which requires an AntiforgeryToken to be sent with each ajax POST.

I have fixed this using an `ajaxPrefilter` like this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions) {
  if (options.type.toUpperCase() == "POST") {
    options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, { __RequestVerificationToken: "antiForgeryToken" }));
  }
});
```

This works great, and adds the `__RequestVerificationToken` to all POSTs.
However, it also causes my data not to be parametrized according to the `traditional` flag.

Does anybody know how I can modify my prefilter to account for this?

Example can be found here:
http://jsbin.com/IxoKIKA/2/edit

Comment: Why are you using an anti forgery token for AJAX? That's totally unnececcery. Validate it's ajax with the appropriate header instead.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum There`s an ``IFilterProvider`` which adds a ``ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`` to all POST requests, including ajax calls. I guess I could check if the specific POST is an XHR call and not add it based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the `traditional` argument to [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). You should write:

```
options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, {
    __RequestVerificationToken: "antiForgeryToken"
}), true);
```

Comment: Strange how I missed that option. Guess I was too fixated on ``$.extend``. Thanks for the help.